# problem in wordpress like delete rows in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

im trying to impelement a technique to delete stories with jquery animation exactly like wordpress

this is my script part :

```
$(function(){
 $('#jqdelete').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('tr.box').animate( { backgroundColor: '#cb5555' }, 500).animate( { height: 0, paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0 }, 500, function() {
   $(this).css( { 'display' : 'none' } );
  });
 });
});
```

but not working 
am i wrong in any part of my code ?

Comment: I'd suspect that this is because table rows do not have `display: block` but use a different display model and so these things tend to not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are multiple delete links, you should use a `class` instead of an id` for delete links:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='jqdelete'>

$(function(){
 $('.jqdelete').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('tr.box').animate( { backgroundColor: '#cb5555' }, 500).animate( { height: 0, paddingTop: 0, paddingBottom: 0 }, 500, function() {
   $(this).css( { 'display' : 'none' } );
  });
 });
});
```